# Vengono anche loro? - explicit subject and subject inversion

Tags: grammar, word-order

I have heard the question:

Vengono anche loro?

Is the subject explicit and put at the end of the sentence for emphasis? Could I simply say:

- Vengono anche?
- Loro vengono anche?

Which form is the most usual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Pure" and "anche" must always be accompanied by the element they refer to. In the question "Vengono?", that is the implicit subject "loro". It is one of the few cases where the personal pronoun cannot be omitted. In the specific case of "anche", it must also precede the subject. Examples:

- Viaggiamo anche/pure noi.
- Viaggiamo noi pure.
- Anche/pure noi viaggiamo.
- Noi pure viaggiamo.

Regarding the examples of the question, the correct alternatives are:

- Vengono anche loro?
- Anche loro vengono?

"Vengono anche" and "Loro vengono anche" are wrong.

Comment: +1, but may I ask how did it happen that you found the answer yourself?

Comment: Searching in blogs and forums, eg (for anche info) https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/position-of-anche-in-the-sentence.599700/ and http://litalianoacasatua.com/anche

Answer (score 0):

“Vengono anche loro” is correct, the other two forms are not! If you want to omit the subject you could say “Vengono?”

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Could you please elaborate on your answer? For example, you  could greatly improve it by explaining why the other two forms are incorrect.

Comment: I'd also like to understand why the other two sentences are incorrect.